# What is the meteor-reaktor equivalent for react-router?

Tags: javascript, meteor, react-router

In MeteorJS one can choose to use Flowrouter, react-router, or many other options for routing. My application is using react-router. In the `meteor-reaktor` package there is an option for `<Route>` called `triggersEnter()` that runs a specified function when the user loads the route.

**Example**

```
  Reaktor.init(
    <Router>
      <Route 
        path="/" 
        name="homePage"
        layout={Layout} 
        content={BlogList} 
        triggersEnter={homePageLogger}/>
    </Router>
  );

  function homePageLogger(context, redirect) {
    if(context.queryParams.forwardToBlog) {
      redirect("/blog");
    }
  }
```

How can I do this in `react-router`? I did not see anything related to this in the documentation and I can not seem to find a package that does this. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **onEnter**:

```
<Route path="/" component={MyComponent} onEnter={componentToRedirectTo}>
```